# CodeSynthesis XSD CXX not parsing XML file, says attributes/elements are not declared

Tags: c++, xml, xml-parsing, xsd, xerces

I am using codesynthesis to generate classes which represent my xsd file. The xml file has been validated against the schema file using an online validation program and it seems to be fine. However upon running my program which simply reads the xml and attempts to create the structures representing the xml file i get exceptions for every element, such as:

```
error: attribute 'dburl' is not declared for element 'quantoptions'
error: no declaration found for element 'option'
error: no declaration found for element 'symbol'
```

Can someone please advise as to why this is happening?

This is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Document created with online XML Editor http://xmlgrid.net 2013/09/08 2:17:41  -->
   <quantoptions dburl="test attribute">
         <option>
               <symbol>test string</symbol>
               <dateselection enddate="2002-09-24" startdate="2002-09-24"></dateselection>
         </option>
         <option>
               <symbol>test string</symbol>
               <dateselection enddate="2002-09-24" startdate="2002-09-24"></dateselection>
               <blackscholes>false</blackscholes>
               <volatility>true</volatility>
         </option>
   </quantoptions>
```

this is the xsd file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="quantoptions">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" name="option">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
                            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="symbol" type="xs:string"/>

                            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="dateselection">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:attribute name="enddate" type="xs:date" use="required"/>
                                    <xs:attribute name="startdate" type="xs:date" use="required"/>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>

                            <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                                <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="blackscholes" type="xs:boolean"/>
                                <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="volatility" type="xs:boolean"/>
                            </xs:choice>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="dburl" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

and finally here is the code, exception is thrown on this line:

> `std::auto_ptr<quantoptions> optionConfig (quantoptions_ (configPath));`

```
    const std::string configPath  = "../config/quantoptions.xml";
    std::auto_ptr<quantoptions> optionConfig (quantoptions_ (configPath));

    optionConfig->dburl();

    for(quantoptions::option_const_iterator i (optionConfig->option().begin()); i != optionConfig->option().end(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout<< i->symbol();
    }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: The schema does not have the ending "</xs:schema>". I guess copying and pasting the schema into stackoverflow failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally fixed the problem, i am not sure if this was documented but although the xml was well formed, code synthesis was looking for the following lines within xml : . so the working xml looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Document created with online XML Editor http://xmlgrid.net 2013/09/08 2:17:41  -->
   <quantoptions xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema.xsd" dburl="test attribute">
         <option>
               <symbol>test string</symbol>
               <dateselection enddate="2002-09-24" startdate="2002-09-24"></dateselection>
         </option>
         <option>
               <symbol>test string</symbol>
               <dateselection enddate="2002-09-24" startdate="2002-09-24"></dateselection>
               <blackscholes>false</blackscholes>
               <volatility>true</volatility>
         </option>
   </quantoptions>
```